# Trying to "censor" all 4 letter words with other methods in C using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make a method called "censor" that finds the 4 letter words in a string using 2 methods ive already made, the new method has to void censor(*start), an explanation as to what I'm doing wrong would be great, thanks!

```
void four_stars(char *start){

int count = 0;
int c = 42;
printf("entered\n");
while(count < 4){
    *start = c;
    start++;
    count++;
}

}
```

and

```
char* find_blank(char *start){

char c;
int space = 127;
int null = 0;

while(*start){

    c = *start;
    int asciiVal = c;
    if(asciiVal == 32 || asciiVal == 3){
        return start;
    }
    start++;
}

}
```

the main method that im using to test it is:

```
int main(){

char myString3[25] = "Test a duck";
printf("The string before: %s\n", myString3);
censor(myString3);
printf("The new string: %s", myString3);
return 0;
}
```

And what I have is

```
void censor(char *start){
char* c = start;
while(*start){
    int i = (int)find_blank(start) - (int)start;
    start = start + i + 1;
    c = start;
    if((int)find_blank(start) - (int)c == 4){
        four_stars(start);

    }
    start++;

}

}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I'm a beginner at the whole C thing, and I forgot to add what I had down for my method, sorry

Comment: `find_blank` : Path exists that does not return a value.

Comment: `start = start + i + 1;` is wrong.

Comment: my reasoning for the start = start + i + 1 is that i sets start equal to where a space is, and I'm wanting to set start to where the next word is located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void four_stars(char *start){
    int count = 0;
    int c = '*';
    //printf("entered\n");
    while(count < 4){
        *start = c;
        start++;
        count++;
    }
}

char* find_blank(char *start){
    char c;

    while(*start){
        c = *start;
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'){
            return start;
        }
        start++;
    }
    return start;
}

char* find_not_blank(char *start){
    char c;

    while(*start){
        c = *start;
        if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n'){
            return start;
        }
        start++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void censor(char *start){
    while(start = find_not_blank(start)){
        int len = find_blank(start) - start;

        if(len == 4){
            four_stars(start);
        }
        start += len;
    }
}

int main(){
    char myString3[25] = "Test a duck";
    printf("The string before: %s\n", myString3);
    censor(myString3);
    printf("The new string: %s", myString3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. When learning C, one of the challenges is getting comfortable with the use of pointers for scanning strings. Along with that comes learning what C library functions are available to help with the scanning when needed. (you can always do it with pointers alone, but there are useful functions that can save you a lot of comparison work)

There are a couple of complicating factors to consider in scanning for 4-letter words. Most notable **punctuation as word ends**. One shortcut for handling multiple possible word ends is simply to create a string holding a collection of characters that can be at the end of a word instead of simple a `space`. Then the C library function `strchr` can be used to check if your ending character is in that collection.

Utilizing that, here is a short example of one approach to scanning a string for 4-letter words that may help you along:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void censor (char *s)
{
    if (!s) return;                 /* validate s               */

    char *sp = s;                   /* start pointer            */
    char *ep = s;                   /* end pointer              */
    char *termchr = " ,.\n\t\0";    /* str of word ends         */

    while (*ep)                     /* for each char in string  */
    {
        if (strchr (termchr, *ep))  /* if char in termchr       */
        {                           /* and num chars == 4       */
            if (ep - ((sp > s) ? ++sp : sp) == 4) 
            {
                while (sp < ep)     /* replace with '*'         */
                    *sp++ = '*';
            }
            else
                sp = ep;            /* if not, just advance sp  */
        }
        ep++;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\n error: insufficient input. Usage:  %s <string>\n\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *str = strdup (argv[1]);   /* make a copy to prevent clobbering argv[1]    */

    printf ("  original string: %s\n", str);

    censor (str);

    printf ("  censored string: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/censor "A sting that has duck you dude."
  original string: A sting that has duck you dude.
  censored string: A sting **** has **** you ****.
```

**Note:** `((sp > s) ? ++sp : sp)` is a simple test that says **if I'm at the beginning, don't advance `sp` before comparing** needed because your are at the beginning of a word already (the first word), not on the last `termchr` you found. You will probably want to come up with a scheme to exclude common words from replacement so you are not censoring words like `this, that, with, most, good, word`(s). That's left to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I greatly appreciate it, although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for it still showed me another way to do it

Comment: That was the purpose in providing it. I see what your are working on, this provides another angle to look at the problem through. Particularly, the use to `strchr` compared to the picket-fence of `or` approach.